# Firebase Cloud Messaging receive notifications on ruby on rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I am having an issue with fcm frontend(JS) part of application. I have implemented the JS code of getting a token from server but unable to receive a notification on my client.

I have my rails project setup and it is running using RPUSH. Rpush script is started as well. I am using CURL to send a push notification. I get success message as CURL response but it is not being received on my end. I have tried serviceworker-rails gem as well.

Service worker is started and I am able to receive token via JS request to fcm.